# Get path to Program Files

Tags: installation, nsis

Inside my NSIS installer, how do I always get the path to the users Program Files, not the `C:/Program Files (x86)/` but always just `C:/Program Files/`

The following variable `$PROGRAMFILES` gives `C:/Program Files (x86)/` on 64 bit and `C:/Program Files/` on others. I want always get the path to the C:/Program Files/ directory.

Comment: Why? If your program is 32-bit, you _should_ be using `C:/Program Files (x86)/`

Answer (score 1):

Example for app that is 64bit only, but you can easily convert it to 32+64bit :)

```
!include x64.nsh

Function .onInit
    ${If} ${RunningX64}
    ;${EnableX64FSRedirection} ;- only if needed
    StrCpy "$INSTDIR" "$PROGRAMFILES64\Modern UI Test"
    ${Else}
    StrCpy "$INSTDIR" "$PROGRAMFILES\Modern UI Test"
    ${EndIf}
FunctionEnd
```

Comment: ${EnableX64FSRedirection} does not change the constants AND you should not keep it enabled for long periods of time, ONLY during file extraction.

Comment: You are right. So simply Jake can use `$PROGRAMFILES64`/`$PROGRAMFILES32` and `$PROGRAMFILES` to call specific Program Files Directory.

Answer (score 1):

If you **always** want to get the native Program Files folder, use $PROGRAMFILES64 but doing that is usually wrong because x86 binaries should not be installed there.

If your installer has both x86 and x64 binaries you can use $PROGRAMFILES64:

```
!include x64.nsh

InstallDir "$PROGRAMFILES64\MyApp"

Section
SetOutPath $InstDir
${If} ${RunningX64}
  File "x64\myapp.exe"
${Else}
  File "x86\myapp.exe"
${EndIf}
SectionEnd
```